# jquery ui slider with tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, slider

Is it possible to have tooltip in jquery ui slider? Or is there other/better slider plugins with this in it already?

Also if i use jquery ui's range slider, is it possible to have two different kind of tabs (the thing that you slide)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery UI slider how to make a box follow the handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582564/jquery-ui-slider-how-to-make-a-box-follow-the-handler)

Answer (score 1):

I dont see why it wouldnt be possible. You just have to add the tool tipping to the building process.. i havent used the sliders much so im not sure what events they offer but if there is an init type hook you could attach the tip there as part of the initialization process.

As far as the "tab" its controlled by css so if you slap a class or id on the slider source element you can target it that way. to add for varying looks between different sliders.