# Jquery UI slider how to make a box follow the handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a div that should follow the handler as it is seen here:
http://m1.dk/Priser/#tab:#calc,#abb

My JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/2/

I also want to make a calculation on the UI value that should appear in the box.

Here is a illustration what I want to achieve: 
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input id="sliderValue" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 // Pris slider
$("#slider").slider({value:'',min: 0,max: 150,step: 1, range: 'min',
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).html( ui.value + ' timer');
    }
});

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );


});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I hope that's the effect you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/11/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#slider").slider({value:'', min: 0, max: 150, step: 1, range: 'min'});

    var thumb = $($('#slider').children('.ui-slider-handle'));   
    setLabelPosition();    

    $('#slider').bind('slide', function () {        
        $('#sliderValue').val($('#slider').slider('value'));
        setLabelPosition();
    });

    function setLabelPosition() {
        var label = $('#sliderValue');
        label.css('top', thumb.offset().top + label.outerHeight(true));
        label.css('left', thumb.offset().left - (label.width() - thumb.width())/ 2);  
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input id="sliderValue" />
```

**CSS**

```
#sliderValue {
    position:absolute;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Best regards!

Comment: This does not work for "clicking", which is considered a "slide" in the slider.

Answer (score 6):

I have modifiered your jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dr5UR/

```
$("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('#sliderValue').css('left', event.clientX).val(ui.value);
    }
}));
```

I make use of the slide event of the [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-slide).

The slide event got two arguments:

1. **event**

   This object contains several informations about the event itself. The time of triggering, the key which has been pressed or the coordinates of the mouse at the moment of triggering. The *clientX* property contains the position we need to set to the moving object.
2. **ui**

   The ui object comes from jQuery UI itself. It basicly just contains the value. Additionally it contains the anchor which is used for dragging too. But you can't use its position, cause the slide event takes effect before the anchor takes its new position.

---

The `#slideValue` input needs to have `position: absolute;`, cause I work with the left position attribute in CSS. You could also set the `margin-left` value, without need to set the `position` to `absolute`.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually quite easy (and very useful) to turn this into a simple jQuery plugin. Like so:

<strike>JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/huYRL/</strike>

<strike>Note that I've added support for moving the slider by entering a value into the `#sliderValue`.</strike>

[ Code sample removed ]

<strike>You could also choose to remove `#sliderValue` from the HTML and let the plugin create it for you. In that case, you would rewrite the plugin so it would be called on the slider, instead of on `#sliderValue`. In my opinion, that would be a much neater solution.</strike>

### Update

Based on your comments (and re-reading your question), I've rewritten the plugin example.

If I understand correctly, you want to do some calculations based on the value of the slider and display the result of those calculations in the label below the slider handle. The following should make that really easy.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/q5qg7/

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

**Plugin**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.sliderLabel = function(options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            marginTop: 2,
            // Margin between the slider handle and the label (in pixels)
            callback: function(value) {
                return 'Value: ' + value;
            }
        }, options);

        return this.each(function() { // <- maintains chainability
            var slider = $(this);
            var handle = slider.children('.ui-slider-handle');
            var data = slider.data('sliderLabel');

            if (handle.length === 0) {
                // $(this) isn't a slider (it has no handle)
                console.log('[SliderLabel] Error: sliderLabel() can only be called on a slider.');
                return;
            }

            if (data === undefined) {
                // First time sliderLabel() is called on this slider
                data = {
                    label: $('<div class="ui-slider-label" />').css('position', 'absolute'),
                    callback: settings.callback
                };

                data.label.insertAfter(slider);

                function updateLabel() {
                    var value = slider.slider('value');
                    var labelText = data.callback(value);

                    data.label.html(labelText);
                    data.label.css('top', handle.offset().top + handle.outerHeight() + settings.marginTop);
                    data.label.css('left', handle.offset().left - ((data.label.width() - handle.width()) / 2));
                }

                updateLabel();
                slider.bind('slide', updateLabel);

            } else {
                // sliderLabel() was called before; just update the callback:
                data.callback = settings.callback;
                updateLabel();
            }

            // Save (or update) the data inside the slider:
            slider.data('sliderLabel', data);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**Usage**

```
$("#slider").slider();

$("#slider").sliderLabel({
    callback: function(value) {
        return value + '%';
    }
});
```

As you can see, the plugin is now called on the slider itself. You can now provide the plugin with a callback, which allows you to do some calculations and return a correctly formatted label (HTML is allowed).

In the example above, the callback simply takes the `value` that is passed to the callbackand appends `'%'`.

Comment: It is not the input I want to follow the slider but a div that have the same value as the input field. http://jsfiddle.net/VnAXZ/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VnAXZ/4/ - Strange when use first drag the handle to the right and then to the left the width changes..

Comment: @Railsbeginner: yes, I'd noticed that strange behaviour as well. For some reason, `handle.offset()` returns different values when moving the handle left as when moving it right. It's off by `5px`. I'll try to have a look at the slider plugin's source code later, when I have some more time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example for a slider with two handles

[image]

```
   $('#slider').slider({
        range: true,
        min: 500,
        max: 10000,
        step: 100,
        values: [1000, 2000],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#min-price').html('$' + ui.values[0]);
            $('#min_budget').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#max-price').html('$' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#max_budget').val(ui.values[1]);
            }

            //move labels when handles are moved
            moveValueLabels();
        }
    });

    //move the value labels directly under the handles
    function moveValueLabels() {
        var pos_first_handle = $('.ui-slider-handle:first').position();
        var pos_last_handle = $('.ui-slider-handle:last').position();
        $('#min-price').css('left', (pos_first_handle.left - ($('#min-price').width()/2)));
        $('#max-price').css('left', (pos_last_handle.left - ($('#max-price').width()/2)));
    }

    //set initial positioning of labels when page is loaded
    moveValueLabels();
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
    overflow: visible;
    #min-price {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding:0;
    }
    #max-price {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding:0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
    width: 200px;
}
#sliderValue {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: '',
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    range: 'min',
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $('.ui-slider-handle').append('<input id="sliderValue" />');
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#sliderValue").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yBfTy/4/

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I would have done and is also the most simple solution

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to take a look at alternative solutions with jQuery plugins such as:

- http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ui-slider
- http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/

Answer (score 0):

Taking your jsfiddle.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input id="sliderValue" />
```

CSS:

`#sliderValue{width:50px;}`

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 // Pris slider
$("#slider").slider({value:'',min: 0,max: 150,step: 1, range: 'min',
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#sliderValue" ).val( ui.value + ' timer');
        var offset = $(this).find('a').css("left");
        $("#sliderValue").css("margin-left", offset);
    }
});

    $( "#sliderValue" ).val($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ));


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just:  http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/21/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 150,
        step: 1,
        range: 'min',
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var offsetLeft = $(this).find(".ui-slider-handle").offset().left;
            $( "#sliderValue" )
                .val( ui.value + ' timer')
                .css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "left": offsetLeft
                });
        }
    });
});
```

The slide callback is called every time you move your handle:

`offsetLeft` is the offset of the handle.

`$( "#sliderValue" )` is your input.