# jQuery-ui slider handle with inputfield following not working when page is centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

Im trying to make a input field follow the handle bar of the jQuery handle-bar. It works somehow right when using the top answer at: [Jquery UI slider how to make a box follow the handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582564/jquery-ui-slider-how-to-make-a-box-follow-the-handler)

But it doesn't work properly when having the slider inside a container with `margin:0 auto;` and `position:relative;`

You can see what I'm talking about [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/147/)

Any help or suggestions appreciated, but I really need my site to be centered.

Thanks in advance, cookies will be rewarded

Edit: I wish the input to appear below the handle-bar

Comment: Where the input is supposed to be? below the handle or at one level with the handle and right to it?

Comment: Only below the handle at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that is what you need: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z3xV3/150/)

you simply need to change this line in your code:

```
label.css('left', thumb.offset().left - (label.width() - thumb.width())/ 2);
```

To this:

```
label.css('left', thumb.position().left - (label.width() / 2));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! You have no idea how happy you just made me :) Thanks a million times!!