# JQuery slider: lag adding a label next to the handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a similar design goal to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582564/jquery-ui-slider-how-to-make-a-box-follow-the-handler) about adding a label to a JQuery slider that shows the current value of the slider while the user is dragging the slider. The problem I have with those answers is that the `slide` event triggers when the slider is about to move to the new location, and provides a `ui` object with the new value. Well and good, but the only *position* of the slider that I can find a way to get hold of is the old, not new, location. With enough steps on the slider this isn't really noticeable, but if I reduce the number of steps you can see that the label appears next to where the slide handle *used to be*.

I've updated the jsFiddle from the other question to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mcuf6/2/

So, tl;dr: how can I avoid lag in drawing a slider label while the user is dragging the handle, by getting the final location of the slider handle during a slide event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
This little hack should do exactly what you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        range: 'min',
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var that = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
            var offsetLeft = that.find(".ui-slider-handle").offset().left;
            $( "#sliderValue" )
                .val( ui.value )
                .css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "left": offsetLeft
                });
        },1);
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mcuf6/6/

Comment: Yes, I know I can update the slider after the change is complete, but the design goal I'm trying to meet is to show the value *before* the user makes the decision where to release the drag action.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to fit your needs. When in doubt - use timeout ;)

Comment: That's ... extremely cunning! Thanks