# How to make a tip to follow the handler of slider with PyQT?

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qslider

A simple question, I am looking for a effect in pyqt like this:

[Jquery UI slider how to make a box follow the handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582564/jquery-ui-slider-how-to-make-a-box-follow-the-handler)

But those code is JQuery and I am trying to achieve it with PyQT

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT example!")
        slider = QtGui.QSlider(self)
        slider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        slider.move(50, 50)
        slider.valueChanged.connect(self.value_changed)
        self.show()

    def value_changed(self, value):
        QtGui.QToolTip.showText(QtGui.QCursor.pos(), str(value), self)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code successfully made tip balloon follow the cursor.
Now is it possible to make the tip follow my slider handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not that simple. Here's my not perfect solution:

1. First, we need to keep track of the `QSlider`, so you need to replace all `slider` by `self.slider`.
2. From the `QSlider`, we can extract the rectangle that contains the handle:

   ```
   style=self.slider.style()
   opt=QtGui.QStyleOptionSlider()
   self.slider.initStyleOption(opt)
   rectHandle=style.subControlRect(QtGui.QStyle.CC_Slider,opt, QtGui.QStyle.SC_SliderHandle,self)
   ```
3. `rectHandle` is a `QRect`, and has several method the get a position in pixels.
   You can either can an `int` with `QRect.bottom()`, `QRect.right()`... or a `QPoint` with `QRect.center()`, `QRect.bottomRight`... All position will be relative to the parent widget, here the slider.
   As an example, to get the absolute position of the rectangle's bottom right corner, you can do:

   ```
   myPoint=rectHandle.bottomRight()+self.slider.pos()
   ```
4. **To improve:** finding the right position for the tool tip
   Bellow my best attempt, with some magic numbers:

   ```
   magicX = 5
   magicY = 15

   x = rectHandle.right() + rectHandle.width() + self.slider.pos().x() + magicX
   y = rectHandle.bottom() + rectHandle.height() + self.slider.pos().y() + magicY
   ```
5. Of course, we need to show the tooltip at our custom position:

   ```
   QtGui.QToolTip.showText(QtCore.QPoint(x,y), str(value), self)
   ```

NB:
All the computing is done in `value_changed` method.

Answer (score 7):

I like @tmoreau's idea, but it is better to put new logic into a subclass of QSlider:

```
class TipSlider(QtGui.QSlider):
    def __init__(self, *args, tip_offset=QPoint(0, -45)):
        super(QtGui.QSlider, self).__init__(*args)
        self.tip_offset = tip_offset

        self.style = QtGui.QApplication.style()
        self.opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionSlider()

        self.valueChanged.connect(self.show_tip)
        # self.enterEvent = self.show_tip
        # self.mouseReleaseEvent = self.show_tip

    def show_tip(self, _):
        self.initStyleOption(self.opt)
        rectHandle = self.style.subControlRect(self.style.CC_Slider, self.opt, self.style.SC_SliderHandle)

        pos_local = rectHandle.topLeft() + self.tip_offset
        pos_global = self.mapToGlobal(pos_local)
        QtGui.QToolTip.showText(pos_global, str(self.value()), self)
```